# Drupal ajax form to upload image can't update nodejs socket content

Tags: ajax, node.js, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to make a chat in a drupal7 site.

And I choose the [nodejs_chat](https://drupal.org/project/nodejs%5fchat).

The module only allow us input some text message to each us, but is not enough for us .

We also need to upload image.

So I make a ajax form under the chat in the page, which can upload the image.

The form code :

```
function _test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['image_fid'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#submit' => array('_test_form_submit'),
    '#validate' => array(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_test_ajax_ab_callback',
      'progress' => array(
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => '',
      ), 
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

And its submit hander code :

```
function _test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['image_fid'] != 0) {
    // The new file's status is set to 0 or temporary and in order to ensure
    // that the file is not removed after 6 hours we need to change it's status
    // to 1. Save the ID of the uploaded image for later use.
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['image_fid']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    // When a module is managing a file, it must manage the usage count.
    // Here we increment the usage count with file_usage_add().
    file_usage_add($file, 'test', 'test_image', 1);

    // Save the fid of the file so that the module can reference it later.

    global $user;
    $img = theme('image_style', array('path' => $file->uri, 'style_name' => 'medium'));

    $message = (object) array(
      'channel' => 'Chat__testing_test_1',
      'callback' => 'nodejsChatMessageHandler',
      'data' => array(
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'msg' => 'upload image',
        'img' => $img,
      ),
    );
    nodejs_send_content_channel_message($message);
  }
}
```

In the form submit handler, I just do two things:

1) Save the file, and theme it.

2) Use the [nodejs](https://drupal.org/project/nodejs) API `nodejs_send_content_channel_message` to insert content to the nodejs socket.

But now, there's a big problem.

If there're A, B, C people in the same chatroom.

When A upload the image, B and C all can see the image, but A can't.

And I found all drupal ajax have the problem, not update the nodejs socket content of the user ( who launch the ajax ) .

If I use a custom ajax ( Write something like $.ajax by myself ) , it will OK.

Does anyone have a good idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help but here is my case:

I modified chatroom module (with drupal nodejs integration module) so as to add image upload.

My submit form is exactly like yours and the result was like you describe here : no image for the owner before refresh but displayed for others.

On server, the only one diference between text message and image message was clienSocketId.
 - client id for image (not working) 
 - empty for text (working)

So i modified nodejs integration module, forcing clienSocketId to be empty.

I still don't know how the text message of the original chat module has already an empty clienSocketId and if the callback behavior works as designed but it solve my problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found the key [link](http://rylyn.org/article/solution-drupal-core-ajax-interrupt-nodejs-socket-update)